# CSS ::after selector

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use the CSS after selector to insert pipes between items of an unordered list. The pipes are not showing up in the browser. Here is my code:
CSS:

```
li.link::after{
content: " | ";
color: white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="navi">
       <li class="links"><a href="was">wut</a></li>
       <li class="links"><a href="wie">Y</a></li>
       <li class="links"><a href="memes">memes</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: link != links ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif lol id10t issue. thx my d00d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help.

```
ul#navi li {
    display:inline;
}
ul#navi li + li::before {
    content: " | ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

css code:

```
li.links::after{
  content: " | ";
  color: white;
}
```